# How to find all rows in an array containing a specific month/year

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, date, search

Find all rows in an array for specific month

I am trying to find all rows in an array that contain a specific month and year (first column is a date column). I need to copy columns A to I for each of these rows into another workbook.
I am fairly new to VBA, and I know I need a For Each loop, but not sure how to make it look for the month/year part of the date only? I'm using dd/mm/yyyy format, for reference.

I have not yet got to the point of trying anything, as I've been stumped by the month/year problem.

EDIT: Here's the final code that worked:

```
  Dim rngInput As Range, nTargetYear As Integer, nTargetMonth As Integer
Dim rngRow As Range, vntInput As Variant, nYear As Integer, nMonth As 
Integer
Dim rngTarget As Range

' Set the input range, target workbook and worksheet before the loop
' I'll leave this up to you, since we don't know what that looks like in 
your case
Set rngInput = wsTEff.Range("A15:A500")

' Define desired month & year (Jan 2023 for example)
nTargetYear = year0
nTargetMonth = mnthnum

' Loop through each row in the input range
Dim i As Integer
i=0
For Each rngRow In rngInput.Rows
vntInput = rngRow.Cells(1, 1)  ' Dates in Column A

If IsDate(vntInput) = True Then  ' Ensure Excel sees the value as a date
    
    nYear = year(vntInput)
    nMonth = Month(vntInput)
    
    ' Is the date within your target month/year?
    If nYear = nTargetYear And nMonth = nTargetMonth Then
        
        Set rngTarget = wsnew.Range("A5").Offset(i, 0)
                        
        ' Copy columns A-I of the source to the target
        rngRow.Resize(1, 9).Copy
        rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        i = i + 1
    End If
End If
Next rngRow
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started. It assumes the dates in column A are actual Excel dates that are simply formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`, NOT text that look like dates but Excel doesn't see as dates. If they are text you'd have to convert them to dates to use this process.

You'll see 2 lines that say "YOUR CODE HERE". That's where you define your source and target. You haven't provided enough info for us to help there. But this will help you with the month/year problem that has you stumped.

```
Sub MonthYearCopy()
    Dim rngInput As Range, nTargetYear As Integer, nTargetMonth As Integer
    Dim rngRow As Range, vntInput As Variant, nYear As Integer, nMonth As Integer
    Dim rngTarget As Range, wkbkTarget As Workbook, wkshTarget As Worksheet
    
    ' Set the input range, target workbook and worksheet before the loop
    ' I'll leave this up to you, since we don't know what that looks like in your case
    ' YOUR CODE HERE
    
    ' Define desired month & year (Jan 2023 for example)
    nTargetYear = 2023
    nTargetMonth = 1
    
    ' Loop through each row in the input range
    For Each rngRow In rngInput.Rows
        vntInput = rngRow.Cells(1, 1)  ' Dates in Column A
        
        If IsDate(vntInput) = True Then  ' Ensure Excel sees the value as a date
            nYear = Year(vntInput)
            nMonth = Month(vntInput)
            
            ' Is the date within your target month/year?
            If nYear = nTargetYear And nMonth = nTargetMonth Then
                
                ' Set the output range (rngTarget) for this row
                ' YOUR CODE HERE
                
                ' Copy columns A-I of the source to the target
                rngRow.Resize(1, 9).Copy rngTarget
                
            End If
        End If
    Next rngRow
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Richard
. I will have a play with that later today and see how I go. Cheers.

Comment: Your questions will be better received by the SO community if you make an effort first, and post what you've tried when you're stumped. Please read the SO guidelines at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Richard,
I have the code partially working: I can get it to copy each appropriate row from the first sheet into the entire target range of the target sheet. So the entire range ends up filled with only data from the last row for the year and month selected.

Is this a problem with the rngTarget I have selected? "A5:A10" is the target range, but I need each row to copy to the next row down. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Kim, please post your code (edit your original question to include the code). It sounds like a simple problem that can be fixed easily. If we see your code we can make meaningful suggestions. Something to keep in mind, SO is not just about answering your question, it's about answering similar questions for anyone else with a similar problem. With your code posted, others can see more easily the problem and its solution(s). Best!

Comment: Thanks once again! I have put the final code into the question so others can access it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard
I have tried to add a Do While loop into it so that it stops after doing 5 iterations of the correct month and year (as there will never be more than this). I'm still getting only the final result, but in all 5 rows of my target range (A5 to A10)
Here is how I have changed it:

```
  Dim rngInput As Range, nTargetYear As Integer, nTargetMonth As Integer
Dim rngRow As Range, vntInput As Variant, nYear As Integer, nMonth As Integer
Dim rngTarget As Range

' Set the input range, target workbook and worksheet before the loop
' I'll leave this up to you, since we don't know what that looks like in your case
Set rngInput = wsTEff.Range("A15:A500")

' Define desired month & year (Jan 2023 for example)
nTargetYear = year0
nTargetMonth = mnthnum

' Loop through each row in the input range
For Each rngRow In rngInput.Rows
    vntInput = rngRow.Cells(1, 1)  ' Dates in Column A
    
    If IsDate(vntInput) = True Then  ' Ensure Excel sees the value as a date
        
        nYear = year(vntInput)
        nMonth = Month(vntInput)
        
        ' Is the date within your target month/year?
        If nYear = nTargetYear And nMonth = nTargetMonth Then
            Dim i As Integer
            i = 0
            Do While i < 5
            Set rngTarget = wsnew.Range("A5").Offset(i, 0)
                            
            ' Copy columns A-I of the source to the target
            rngRow.Resize(1, 9).Copy
            rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            i = i + 1
            Loop
        End If
    End If
Next rngRow
```

Comment: And now I can see why this isn't working, but not how to fix it. Mainly I think I just need the range to add an offset each time we get a true result.

Comment: OK, solved it by moving the i=0 outside the For Each loop, and removing the Do While loop entirely.